# What is the value of this resistor?

Tags: resistors, motor-controller, speed, schematic

I am trying to fix a rotary tool's AC powered DC motor controller, there is a resistor that has been burned out, I want to replace it for a new one, my question is how do I find the value of the resistor since I can't see clearly the color coding anymore and I don't have the schematic.

Thank you in advance for your help.

(please see the pictures)[image][image][image]

Comment: and you think we can see the colours any better than you can? Look for spares for that machine : maybe you'll get lucky and find one with a good photo.

Comment: Also there's a reason that the resistor burned up, possibly not having anything to do with the resistor itself.  So just replacing the resistor might not fix the problem and might just result in another burned resistor.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I have tried that already with no luck, the model of the rotary tool is Proxxon IBS/E 38481

Comment: John you may be right, If I replace the resistor with a right one and happens again I will know it is something else.

Comment: What pin of the TRIAC is it connected to? You might be able to calculate how much resistance you need based on the application and the circuit design.

Comment: @bran I can safe you that effort: that resistor being toast means something else is broken, too. Resistors like that one don't just burn for fun. Even if it wasn't the reason, the capacitor that the resistor roasted also has to be replaced. You'll also want to replace the thyristor/TRIAC, being the most likely to have failed. Great! Now you're ordering electronics worth ca 1,50€ for 5€ shipping, so you add four rectifier diodes for a total of 40ct and the other yellow capacitor to your order.

Comment: @Ali Kavoosi middle pin

Comment: @Marcus Müller I can replace all of them I just need to know the value of the resistor to buy it, thank you for the heaps up

Comment: Is that a one sided circuit board?  How about a picture of the other side?

Comment: Check C3 for shorted condition (out of circuit).

Comment: Is it really an AC speed controller? the motor is DC or AC?

Comment: Maybe you don't care but this is a DC motor controller. I propose to edit and change from "AC speed controller" to "AC powered DC motor controller".

Comment: @Paul Ghobril I have updated it, thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on what's visible in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jFxUrYEduJg&ab_channel=JWParadise), the resistor (**R1**) appears to be 1k Ω ±5% (~0.5 W?).  Here are some screenshots:

[image: Front of board]
Front of board.  A bit blurry but the best shot I could find of the resistor.

[image: Back of board]
Back of board.  Resistor is across the two right-most pads on the lower edge.

And here's a schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ19sl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Schematic is laid out to match part locations on the board as viewed from the top.  **R1** is the burned-out resistor that the question is asking about.  It's not very visible but the OP has verified that the part labelled **D5** is a DIAC (part marked `DB3`).

Here's the schematic redrawn a bit more clearly:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7LfFC.png)</sup>

Use of a DIAC on the gate of a TRIAC is [discussed here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/cd00022856-triac-overvoltage-protection-using-a-transil-stmicroelectronics.pdf).  The datasheet for the DIAC can be [found here](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/db4.pdf) (thanks to @PaulGhobril for finding that).  The datasheet for the TRIAC can be [found here](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/389/bta16-954517.pdf); the part used on this board does not require a snubber.

My guess is that in addition to **R1**, at a minimum **C3** is probably also toast (shorted).

Comment: In the schematic, D5 must be a DIAC. Inputs 1 and 4 are connected to the AC power supply. 2 and 3 are connected to the DC motor.

Comment: @Alex Hajnal, thank you for your detailed explanation, it looks that C3 is good I removed it and tested it the reading was 100.8nf ESR=15Ohms, I am going to replace the resistor with a 1kohm one, I will let you know what happens.

Comment: @Paul Ghobril D5 component says DB3

Comment: @alexhajnal it is a Diac indeed. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/db4.pdf.

Comment: How important is the tolerance and wattage of the resistor in this circuit?, I have a 1k Ω but I don't know the power nor tolerance.

Comment: @bran I don't have too much experience with this type of circuit but I believe the current running through that resistor should *normally* be pretty low. There's a bit of variation from model to model but the 9.5×3.3mm ones with tan lacquer are typically ~0.5W to 1W.  The color of the last band on a resistor gives the tolerance: silver = ±10%, gold = ±5%, red = ±2%, brown = ±1%.  5% ones typically have tan lacquer and 1% ones blue lacquer.  For this circuit the resistor tolerance probably doesn't matter much. A tolerance of 5% or better (e.g. 1%) should be fine.

Comment: Thanks again @Alex Hajnal, I just noticed that middle pin of the TRIAC is broken probably got shorted, I just found this video with a similar speed controller but doesn't have a bridge rectifier ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jo7dMVLZzBU&t=246s&ab_channel=Robojax  ) Those modules are very cheap, do you think could that work with my rotary tool with an input voltage of 115v, and what things should I have into consideration before switching it with one of those modules?

Comment: @bran The controller in the video you linked to is for an AC motor.  Your tool uses a DC motor and will probably react poorly to AC.  Why don't you source replacements for all of the parts from a reputable supplier such as [Mouser](https://mouser.com), [Digikey](https://digikey.com), [Newark](https://newark.com), or the like and do a full rebuild?  If you go that route pay special attention to the voltage and class ratings on the capacitors.  The diodes, DIAC, etc. should have part numbers marked on them.  The only part that would be tricky to replace is the potentiometer.

Comment: @Alex Hajnal Yes you are right, I will start testing components and replacing the resistor and TRIAC first

Comment: Yea, if the middle pin on the TRIAC got disconnected (it connects to "AC 1" on the schematic) then the full current flow would have passed through that resistor.  Hard to say precisely what else might have blown.  BTW, I'd put hot glue to replace any glue that you remove.  If you don't then pins could snap from the vibration.

Comment: @bran Regarding capacitor C1 in particular, it's probably marked as being a class X capacitor.  Make sure that any replacement you get is the same class and voltage.  The class of capacitor (e.g. X or Y) indicates how it behaves if it fails.  [See here](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/technical-articles/safety-capacitor-class-x-and-class-y-capacitors/) for more details.